# How to make sidekiq jobs perform on the same AWS EC2 Instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sidekiq

I have a ruby on rails application where I generate files in the background using Sidekiq. After the file is created, I will attempt to fetch the file. The problem is that sometimes, most likely due to the load balancer, the sidekiq job performs in another of my ec2 instance so the file is created, but I can't fetch it from my current instance.

Is there a way to ensure a request (doesn't specifically have to be about Sidekiq because I feel this issue can also be applied more generically) is performed through the same ec2 instance?

Comment: https://www.mikeperham.com/2013/11/13/advanced-sidekiq-host-specific-queues/

Answer (score 0):

Enable load balancer sticky sessions. This link is for the Classic ELB, but the other ELBs also support this feature.

[Configure Sticky Sessions for Your Classic Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-sticky-sessions.html)